# Is there a way to share storage / variable between extension instances?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was not able to find an answer to this in the documentation so I want to try here.

One of the websites we use in our company requires to change password every month, but provides no notification or notice, they just block our account after a month when the password was not changed.

My idea was to build an extension that would notify users of this website to change the password, when the time comes.

Let's say 3 people install this extension and one of them changes the password (clicks a button to confirm the change in the extension window, let's say).

Is there a way to share this information, that the password was changed, so that all 3 instances of the extension also have the same timer from the last password change?

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You say: "let's say 3 people". So are we talking about an account shared between several people?
If so, you could warn everyone by sending first a message to a server (with a POST\GET request).

Now, from your extension you can get the info by

- querying the server (cyclically or at a strategic point before having to use that password) or
- staying tune to receive a message sent by that server via a server event message (EventSource) or
- waiting the message sent by that server (or a third-party service) via a Web Push Notification.

At this point you will only have to locally overwrite the old password with the new one.

If, on the other hand, the account refers to a single person who accesses from multiple browsers\devices, then things are simpler. You can store that password in the sync storage (chrome.storage.sync) and use the extension with an always connected profile.

But be aware!: Local and sync storage areas should not store confidential user data because they are not encrypted.

**EDIT (2023-05-02 16:36 UTC+2):**

Re-reading your initial question, another way to procced came to my mind.
It's what I implemented in one of my extensions which, to be fully functional, must be able to access the updated password of the Active Directory of a certain domain (within my organization).

In my use case, I save the password in synchronized storage and use the extension on different devices.
When I go to change the password because it is about to expire, I will find the extension with the old password memorized which obviously will reject all requests.

To avoid having my user\account locked (due to company policies) I make sure that the extension does not try to request any domain resources (getting a server denial as response) more than 2 times.
Obviously, here I can't know how your website will behave (whether or not it will block the account on the umpteenth attempt).
By server denial, I mean (at least in my case) a response that explicitly states that the password is incorrect or has expired.
Here the cases multiply because you may be dealing with an XML, JSON or HTML response that you will have to analyze beforehand "by hand" to identify a field-value or a node\element with something like: "Password expired" or "Password incorrect".
When you have found this discriminating element, you will then have to search for it in the response but this time through the extension.

On the second failed attempt (perhaps spaced out by a certain arbitrary amount of time) I bring up a message (alert, dialog, popup, etc.) which warns the user that the password is invalid and therefore must be changed.
By changing it I mean within the extension to align with the activeDirectory or website one.
At this point I imagine you already have an extension page (or a form somewhere) that allows you to save\modify the password.
All you have to do is enter the new password and save.

At this point you will need to use this new password to attempt a login stage.
If this is successful (again you will have to query the response) then it will mean that the password is aligned with the "external" one,
you can reset the counter that stored the number of failed attempts (for the next time) and the game can be considered done.
Now (if you want) you can notify the other users of the password change in one of the ways I suggested before (or at least even with more trivial systems: voice, pigeon, etc.)

**Whether the website will block the account only after a couple of attempts** (potentially made by different users on different devices with different IPAs)
then it is highly recommended to share the information: "WARNING PASSWORD EXPIRED, DO NOT MAKE ANY FURTHER ATTEMPTS" through a server which will then spread this WARNING as soon as possible
to all users (here you could use either a server event message or a web push notification)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information. The issue is that it is supposed to be 3 different users on 3 different devices. I saw some info about the storage, but did not find how I could possibly share it between users, if at all possible. I guess the server POST/GET requests should do the trick.

Comment: I also do not need to store the password, I just need to update the timer for all the other users as well, they will pass the information between them, I just need the notifications to be synchronized, therefore serverside counter and GET request seems like the best option to me.